# Scheduling Algorithm with limitations

Tags: algorithm

Thanks to user3125280, D.W. and Evgeny Kluev the question is updated.

I have a list of webpages and I must download them frequently, each webpage got a different download frequency. Based on this frequency we group the webpages in 5 groups:

```
Items in group 1 are downloaded once per 1 hour
items in group 2 once per 2 hours
items in group 3 once per 4 hours
items in group 4 once per 12 hours
items in group 5 once per 24 hours
```

This means, we must download all the group 1 webpages in 1 hour, all the group 2 in 2 hours etc.

I am trying to make an algorithm. As input, I have:

a) `DATA_ARR` = one array with 5 numbers. Each number represents the number of items in this group.

b) `TIME_ARR` = one array with 5 numbers (1, 2, 4, 12, 24) representing how often the items will be downloaded.

b) `X` = the total number of webpages to download per hour. This is calculated using items_in_group/download_frequently and rounded upwards. `If we have 15 items in group 5, and 3 items in group 4, this will be 15/24 + 3/12 = 0.875 and rounded is 1.`

Every hour my program must download at max `X` sites. I expect the algorithm to output something like:

```
Hour 1: A1 B0 C4 D5
Hour 2: A2 B1 C2 D2
...
```

A1 = 2nd item of 1st group
C0 = 1st item of 3rd group

My algorithm must be as efficient as possible. This means:

a) the pattern must be **extendable** to at least 200+ hours
b) **no need to create a repeatable pattern**
c) spaces are **needed** when possible in order to use the absolute minimum bandwidth
d) **never ever download an item more often than the update frequency, no exceptions**

---

**Example:**

```
group 1: 0 items | once per 1 hour
group 2: 3 items | once per 2 hours
group 3: 4 items | once per 4 hours
group 4: 0 items | once per 12 hours
group 5: 0 items | once per 24 hours
```

We calculate the number of items we can take per hour: `3/2+4/4 = 2.5. We round this upwards and it's 3.`

Using pencil and paper, we can found the following solution:

```
Hour 1: B0 C0 B1
Hour 2: B2 C1 c2
Hour 3: B0 C3 B1
Hour 4: B2
Hour 5: B0 C0 B1
Hour 6: B2 C1 c2
Hour 7: B0 C3 B1
Hour 8: B2
Hour 9: B0 C0 B1
Hour 10: B2 C1 c2
Hour 11: B0 C3 B1
Hour 12: B2
Hour 13: B0 C0 B1
Hour 14: B2 C1 c2
and continue the above.
```

We take `C0`, `C1` `C2`, and `C3` once every 4 hours. We also take `B0`, `B1` and `B2` once every 2 hours.

---

**Question: Please, explain to me, how to design an algorithm able to download the items, while using the absolute minimum number of downloads?** Brute force is **NOT** a solution and the algorithm must be efficient CPU wise because the number of elements can be huge.

You may read the answer posted here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19422/12497 as well as the answer posted bellow by user3125280.

Comment: Better, lets call this a c++ question however and remove the tags for all the other languages.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: @paqogomez I see no c++; I removed everything but 'c', gah, missed the std cout

Comment: You should not re-post a deleted question, you should make an effort to fix the [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833162/how-to-solve-this-insane-puzzle), only 10k+ user can actually view it though.

Comment: I added more tags in order to be viewed by more people as i understand and can write code in all languages I tagged. cout is c++ also. Anyway, I am new so I will listen to the seniors here. @Digital_Reality: In the given 'refresh time' we must take at least once each item from that group. you can run my code on codepad.org and see. This will help you understand more.

Comment: Can you provide a source of other implementation cause we can't understood what the puzzle about. is it your's or it's defined by aother one?

Comment: This a personal unique puzzle I am facing. Can you please explain where you don't understand so I can explain it?

Comment: If I understand this, it is a simple modulus calculation *per group*, per cycle (consumed hour). As the "clock" ticks off an hour the "current" number of hours expired mod the refresh rate per group equating to zero will denote whether you extricate an item from that group. Either that or I'm severely misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of this puzzle what should the player do to solve it and what's the rules for it...

Comment: Maybe you should explain what output you would expect from your example program (and why). I don't understand the refresh thing at all, and I don't want to try to understand it from reading your code.

Comment: If the question isn't specific to a language, it shouldn't be tagged with **any** language tag, never mind 4 of them. It should instead be tagged with [tag:language-agnostic] or [tag:pseudocode]. Trying to artificially get more views by adding tags not applicable to the question is not particularly likely to win you many people's favour.

Comment: You are right, but what if I accept ANY language as I can understand all of them?

Comment: I have fixed the bogus tags.

Comment: @Luka the tags indicate a language specific question, not a language specific answer (usually). That's is, they mean 'answer my <language question' not answer my question in <language>

Comment: Some input values make this problem unsolvable. Place one item into each of the groups 2, 3, and 4. X=ceil(1/2+1/3+1/12)=1. I don't see any way how to schedule downloads to satisfy all the requirements (unless we increase X to 2).

Comment: You found a case where the problem can't be solved. What of the following can i do: a) edit the download times, I can set 4 hours instead of 3 b) generate the x with some other way c) say x = x+1. If I say x = x+1, will my question always work, or there will be cases where x will need to be x = x+2?

Comment: a) yes, some sets of download periods make this problem solvable; if every smaller period exactly divides all greater periods (as in case of 4 instead of 3 hours), this problem is always solvable (and with very simple algorithm). b) no idea what do you mean here. c) I don't see any counter-example for `x = x+1` case, but right now I don't have a proof that `x+1` is always enough.

Comment: a) so for example if the 5 times are (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) will this be ok? b) i mean, calculate x with an other way than: items_in_group/download_frequently

Comment: a) yes, (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) is also OK (and 1, 3, 6, 12, 24 and many others); b) I just cannot imagine any reasonable way different from this.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will updated the post using what you write here

Comment: Hey, don't cross-post!  I just learned that this was [cross-posted on CS.StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19411/755), within a space of one or two days.  That violates site rules.  Please don't do that again.  I suggest you pick one of these to close, and flag it to ask the moderator to close that one.  In the future, if you accidentally post on the wrong site, click the "flag" link underneath the question to flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderator to migrate it.  But don't cross-post!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You problem is a typical scheduling problem. These kinds of problems are well studied in computer science so there is a huge array of literature to consult.

The code is kind of like [Deficit round robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficit_round_robin), but with a few simplifications. First, we feed the queues ourself by adding to the `data_to_process` variable. Secondly, the queues just iterate through a list of values.

One difference is that this solution will get the optimal value you want, barring mathematical error.

<strike>Rough sketch: have not compiled (c++11)</strike> unix based, to spec code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include <cmath> //for ceil

#define TIME_SCALE ((double)60.0) //1 for realtime speed

//Assuming you are not refreshing ints in the real case
template<typename T>
struct queue
{
    const std::vector<T> data; //this will be filled with numbers
    int position;

    double refresh_rate; //must be refreshed ever ~ hours
    double data_rate; //this many refreshes per hour
    double credit; //amount of refreshes owed

    queue(std::initializer_list<T> v, int r ) :
        data(v), position(0), refresh_rate(r), credit(0) {
        data_rate = data.size() / (double) refresh_rate;
    }

    int getNext() {
        return data[position++ % data.size()];
    }
};

double time_passed(){
static double total;
//if(total < 20){ //stop early
    usleep(60000000 / TIME_SCALE); //sleep for a minute
    total += 1.0 / 60.0; //add a minute
    std::cout << "Time: " << total << std::endl;
    return 1.0; //change to 1.0 / 60.0 for real time speed
//} else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //keep a list of the queues
    std::vector<queue<int> > queues{
    {{1, 2, 3}, 2},
    {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 3}};

    double total_data_rate = 0;
    for(auto q : queues) total_data_rate += q.data_rate;

    double data_to_process = 0; //how many refreshes we have to do
    int queue_number = 0; //which queue we are processing

    auto current_queue = &queues[0];

    while(1) {
        data_to_process += time_passed() * total_data_rate;
        //data_to_process = ceil(data_to_process) //optional

        while(data_to_process >= 1){
            //data_to_process >= 0 will make the the scheduler more
            //eager in the first time period (ie. everything will updated correctly
            //in the first period and and following periods
            if(current_queue->credit >= 1){
            //don't change here though, since credit determines the weighting only,
            //not how many refreshes are made
                //refresh(current_queue.getNext();
                std::cout << "From queue " << queue_number << " refreshed " <<
                current_queue->getNext() << std::endl;
                current_queue->credit -= 1;
                data_to_process -= 1;
            } else {
                queue_number = (queue_number + 1) % queues.size();
                current_queue = &queues[queue_number];
                current_queue->credit += current_queue->data_rate;
            }
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The example should now compile on gcc with --std=c++11 and give you what you want.

and here is test case output: (for non-time scaled earlier code)

```
Time: 0
From queue 1 refreshed 1
From queue 0 refreshed 1
From queue 1 refreshed 2
Time: 1
From queue 0 refreshed 2
From queue 0 refreshed 3
From queue 1 refreshed 3
Time: 2
From queue 0 refreshed 1
From queue 1 refreshed 4
From queue 1 refreshed 1
Time: 3
From queue 0 refreshed 2
From queue 0 refreshed 3
From queue 1 refreshed 2
Time: 4
From queue 0 refreshed 1
From queue 1 refreshed 3
From queue 0 refreshed 2
Time: 5
From queue 0 refreshed 3
From queue 1 refreshed 4
From queue 1 refreshed 1
```

As an extension, to answer the repeating pattern problem by allowing this scheduler to complete only the first lcm(update_rate * lcm(...refresh rates...), ceil(update_rate)) steps, and then repeating the pattern.

ALSO: this will, indeed, be unsolvable sometimes because of the requirement on hour boundaries. When I use your unsolvable example, and modify time_passed to return 0.1, the schedule is solved with updates every 1.1 hours (just not at the hour boundaries!).

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out. It's close to my problem. Can you find any source explaining how this works?

Comment: in this case, it's probably easy enough to work out how many must be extracted from each list per unit time, and then do the extracting at the start of each time unit (hour/second/whatever). I suggested the scheduling analogy since things seemed a little simplified and scheduling could help with more complicated cases

Comment: What you say is correct but really not enough to solve the puzzle.

Comment: My algorithm shares a few things with weighted fair queuing but there are differences also. All in all, reading those very few sites in the web regarding the subject doesn't help me solve this.

Comment: @Luka i wrote some code before, i'll post it in a couple of minutes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44162/discussion-between-user3125280-and-luka)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but I really don't understand how to modify your code to solve my question.

Comment: Not exactly doing what I was looking for but helped me solving the problem a lot.

Comment: @Luka see the other answer as well - it is simpler and probably more suitable to your requirements

Answer (score 1):

It seems your constraints are all over the place. To quickly summarise my other answer:

- It meets the refresh rates only on average
- It does the least number of downloads at hour intervals required to fulfil the above

It was based on these (sometimes unfulfillable) constraints

1. Update at discrete, 1 hour intervals
2. Update the fewest items each time
3. Update each item at fixed intervals

and broke 3.

Since both the hourly interval and least-each-time constraints are not really necessary, I will give a simpler, better answer here, which breaks 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TIME_SCALE ((double)60.0)

//Assuming you are not refreshing ints in the real case
template<typename T>
struct queue
{
    const std::vector<T> data; //this is the data to refresh
    int position; //this is the data we are up to
    double refresh_rate; //must be refreshed every this many hours
    double data_rate; //this many refreshes per hour
    double credit; //is owed this many refreshes
    const char* name;//a name for each queue

    queue(std::initializer_list<T> v, int r, const char* n ) :
        data(v), position(0), refresh_rate(r), credit(0), name(n) {
        data_rate = data.size() / (double) refresh_rate;
    }

    void refresh() {
        std::cout << "From queue " << name << " refreshed " << data[position++ % data.size()] << "\n";
    }
};

double time_passed(){
static double total;
    usleep(60000000 / TIME_SCALE); //sleep for a minute
    total += 1.0; //add a minute
    std::cout << "Time: " << total << std::endl;
    return 1.0; //change to 1.0 / 60.0 for real time speed
}

int main()
{
    //keep a list of the queues
    std::vector<queue<int> > queues{
        {{1}, 1, "A"},
        {{1}, 2, "B"}};

    while(1) {
        auto t = time_passed();
        for(queue<int>& q : queues) {
            q.credit += q.data_rate * t;
            while(q.credit >= 1){
                q.refresh();
                q.credit -= 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

It has the potential, however, to schedule many refreshes on the same hour. There is a third option as well, which breaks the hour-interval rule and updates only one at a time.

I think this is the easiest and requires the minimal number of updates (like the previous answer) but doesn't break rule 3.