# Is there a solution for this?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

We download 3 webpages per hour max, for 6 hours.

We have to download again and again the same webpage to check for changes.
We have the webpages split in two categories:

```
Priority B: each webpage here must be downloaded once per 2 hours
Priority C: each webpage here must be downloaded once per 3 hours
```

We have 3 items in priority B and 4 in priority C.
This means, for each hour on average:

```
we must download 3/2 = 1.5 B items
we must download 4/3 = 1.333 C items

On 6 hours: (1.5+1.333)*6 = 17 items.
```

This proves the problem may have a solution with 17 steps.

My attempt (using 18 steps):

```
Hour 1: B0 C0 B1
Hour 2: C1 B2 C2
Hour 3: B0 C3 B1
Hour 4: C0 B2 C2
Hour 5: B0 C1 B1
Hour 6: C3 B2 C2
```

The problem:

We take `C0` once every 3 hours. The same applies to `C1` and `C3`. We also take `B0`, `B1` and `B2` once every 2 hours. Those are fine.

We take `C2` once every 2 hours. This puzzles me. Using pencil and paper I failed to mathematically prove that solving the problem is possible by taking `C2` once every 3 hours.

Question: Is it possible, for someone to modify my attempt, to use only 17 steps and download `C2` once every 3 hours?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: please it is, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833368/solve-with-the-minimum-number-of-steps

Comment: This questions would probably get a better answer here: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted it already but no answer

Comment: I don't see any programming aspect here; this seems to just be a maths puzzle.

Comment: I am trying to solve this in 17 steps in order to solve the c++ question I posted above. If you insist, I have no option than to delete this.

Comment: Don't delete it. If people think its off topic they can vote to close.

Comment: @Luka do not download C2 in hour 6 then your done

Comment: The thing loops, if I don't download C2 in hour 6 C2 will be download every 4 hours.

Comment: One thing that occurs to me. Is it actually a problem downloading one more page every six hours? I can't see what problems might be caused but obviously I don't know what you are doing exactly...

Comment: Yes it's absolutely impossible to download more than 3 per hour. This is the main limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you need to stick to doing things on the hour. ie how your time restritions work. IF you keep it the same but fetch C2 at the start of hour 2 and right at the end of hour 4 then there is just short of three hours different and then skipping the C2 in hour 6 and assuming looping then just over three hours between the end of hour 4 and the beginning of hour 2.

Otherwise there is no way of doing it using just time slots. The reason is that you have to have at least one hour where you are checking 2 of the priority C items. Because you check it again three hours later there is an odd hour and an even hour that have 2 priority C checks. Since the B items check on all even or all odd hours then you would be limited to only two of them (one on odd and one on even) so you couldn't do it.

Comment: Good point, give me a moment to understand what you are saying, but from a first look, you seem pretty correct.